# Удаление подстроки с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Подскажите, как сделать чтобы вывести так `Admins` а не так //Admins/

```
preg_replace('/[user]/', '$1', '/user/Admins/');
```

Comment: Не понял. Причём здесь $1?

Comment: Попробуйте ещё `/user/Administrator/`, вы будете удивлены.

Comment: @alexlz: А чё, всё понятно. `e`, `r`, `s` и `u` заменяются на первую скобочную группу, т.е. на ничто.

@Xcho: `/\/user\/(.*)\//`

Comment: @VladD вопросы интересные. Иногда на вопрос "где у меня ошибка?" хочется дать классический ответ...

Comment: @Xcho Xhurshudyan, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

так:

```
preg_replace(':.*/([^/]*)/$:', '$1', '/user/Admins/');
```

http://ideone.com/iz0D7C